# Is there any possible way to call node js function and retrive the returned value on solidity smart contract?

Tags: solidity, blockchain, remix-tests

**In solidity ,**

from solidity, I need to call the JS function that I have created in Node.js

Scenario :
**I tried some encryption on Solidty, but its not working, so what I'm thinking is that I need to call the JS function with the required parameter, and that JS function will do all the encryption I want and return the encrypted value to the same smart contract function.**

**Based on the above scenario, please provide any method on how to call a JS function and get the response from the JS function on the Solidity smart contract.**

If any other alternate option/workaround is available, please let me know.

Any input is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, what you're trying to do is access **off-chain** data (returned by your **JS** function) **on-chain** (via a **Solidity** function).

To achieve this, you've to explore the web3 technology named as [Blockchain Oracle](https://chain.link/education/blockchain-oracles), which facilitates the integration of off-chain (data and computation) with on-chain (logic). One of the most reputable Web3 Oracle Infrastructure is [Chainlink](https://chainlinklabs.com/). You can explore various functionalities provided by them:

1. [Chainlink Functions](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-functions) - the easiest and the most direct way to access custom off-chain data, and store the same on-chain.
2. [Chainlink Any-API](https://docs.chain.link/any-api) - to connect smart contracts to various off-chain data feeds.
3. [Chainlink Node](https://docs.chain.link/chainlink-nodes/v1/running-a-chainlink-node) - if you want to understand the entire process and data flow from off-chain to on-chain.

So, you can choose any of the above options depending on your requirements.

Obviously, you can explore all the options to gain a better overall understanding.